# "It should have killed me, but I hadn't died" - is this sentence correct?

Tags: tense, past-perfect

If it's correct, why the Past Perfect tense has been used here instead of Past Simple?

Comment: My first thought was that it isn't correct. However, there is one context in which it could possibly be used -  when the speaker is looking back to a moment in the past when they had just been through a life-threatening experience and were surprised to be still alive.